# How to select the first child of each element in list in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get the text from the first inner div in each outer div

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">text1</div> 
        <div class="inner">text2</div>
        <div class="inner">text3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">text4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">text5</div>
        <div class="inner">text6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is means retrieving text1, text4, text5

I've experimented with the code shown below:

```
outers = soup.select('body > .outer')
for outer in outers:
    inners = outer.select_one('.inner')
    for inner in inners:
        print(inner.text)
```

But can't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this works,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for outer in soup.find_all('div', class_='outer'):
    inners = outer.find('div', class_='inner')
    for inner in inners:
        print(inner)


# Output as:
#           text1
#           text4
#           text5
```

OR
You can use this way,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for outer in soup.find_all('div', class_='outer'):
    inners = outer.find('div', class_='inner')
    print(inners.get_text())
```

Comment: This gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` after the `for inner in inners:` line

Comment: The edited solution works great! I was trying to iterate over the non-iterable `inners` as it is only a single element. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This code worked for me:

```
[div.find("div", {"class": "inner"}) for div in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "outer"})]
```

That is, a one-line version of the same thing.

Comment: I can't figure out how to print each section of text. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the text in the div? If not; have you tried putting my code in a print() command? If yes, maybe try `div.findAll("div", {"class": "inner"}))[0].text` instead of `div.findAll("div", {"class": "inner"}))[0]`.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, `find_all(...)[0]` is equivalent to `find(...)`.

Comment: Also, you don't have to convert it to a *list*. `find_all` returns a *list*.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it didn't but looks like you're correct.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a print function and wrapping just the list...[0] part in a print function and neither seemed to output anything. I also tried assigning it to a variable to print which I couldn't get to work. Thanks for the concise response though